# How to display Virtual TreeView childs in columns

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Is it possible to display virtual treeview node childs in columns (horizontally) without losing Node.Data properties?

Ok here is the picture :

[image]

Normal treeview is on the left image. On the right side of  image is  two  variants of what I want to achieve

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe with an illustration of your expected output.

Comment: The top view is possible (though it's weird) e.g. by adding some sort of merged node which will hold array of real child nodes whose will be hidden at that time. That way you won't lose your child node data. What data structures do you use ?

Comment: This is a record (10 integer fields and 3 datetime fields). I need to show that processes shown as the children are dependent on each other, so all must be displayed at the same level

Comment: So you're using the same structure for parent and child nodes ?

Comment: Yes, parent data and child data record's has the same structure. The child node's ilustrate actions that can be performed simultaneously, and whose completion is needed to complete action ilustrated by parent node. For example you can cook soup and roast meat at the same time but dinner is formed only after the preparation of both

Comment: Here is a [`dirty, too much hardcoded proof`](http://pastebin.com/L7jdpCvQ) of what I thought. For each parent I've added a *merged node* which is in *classic view* invisible and which holds pointers to real child node data. When the view is switched to *merged view*, real child nodes become hidden and the merged nodes visible. But there's a lot to improve...

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very helpfully!